# How to get a stream from the windows phone API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, protobuf-net

So I'm using protobuff.net to serialize and desirialize data to and from a file. The problem is that the Desirialize and Serialize methods from protobuff takes a stream as a argument. Up until now I was using `System.IO.FileStream` but since I'm porting the game to work for the windows store and windows phone I need to use `Windows.Storage` and `Windows.Storage.Streams`. The question is how do I create a stream from a file on windows phone app.

This is the code for loading :

```
 public static T LoadObjectFromPath<T>(string path)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        T deserializedObject = default(T);
     #if !NETFX_CORE
        using(FileStream f = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open))
        {
              deserializedObject = (T)m_serialiezer.Deserialize(f,null,typeof(T));
        }
#else
       //Write Windows store specific code here
#endif
```

And this is for saving:

```
  public static void SaveObjectToPath<T>(string objectPath, string filename, T serializedObject)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(objectPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(objectPath);
        }
        if(!File.Exists(objectPath + filename))
        {
            File.Create(objectPath + filename);
        }
#if !NETFX_CORE
        using (FileStream f = new FileStream(objectPath + filename, FileMode.Truncate))
        {

            m_serialiezer.Serialize(f, serializedObject);
        }
#else

#endif
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions);k(vs.objectbrowser);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv4.5.1)&rd=true) or the [`WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions);k(vs.objectbrowser);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv4.5.1)&rd=true) -- the methods on both of them should automagically appear as extension methods on the WinRT types (`StorageFile` etc.) if you are `using System.IO;`